# Observe List(Of) additions

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a List (Of customclass).
Somewhere within my code, items are added to this List although they should not.
My code is huge, so I can't easily debug where this occurs.
I was therefore thinking of creating an extension that I can easily break in when an insert / add occurs when I don't expect it.

Can anybody tell me if this is possible, and if yes, how?

I hope that I can then somehow detect the caller (the function) where the additions occur.

Thank you.

Comment: one of the benefits of writing a collection class rather than using a collection object is that you can set a breakpoint in the `Add` method to catch such things.

Comment: Use BindingList(Of T) AddNew event or ObservableCollection(Of T)

Comment: You can always use a decorator pattern and implement your own logging decorator that implements `IList(Of T)` that you wrap `List(Of T)` with. Then replace all occurrences of `List(Of T)` with your new class and you can log every list operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already have it:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class clsCellListExtender

    Public Class List(Of T)
        Inherits Collection(Of T)

        Private _iID As Integer = 0

        Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As T)
            'your checks here

            If TypeOf (item) Is clsCell Then
                _iID += 1
                Dim nCell As clsCell = TryCast(item, clsCell)
                nCell.TempID = _iID
            End If

            MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

I declare my list as clsCellListExtender.List(Of clsCell).